# Change Guest session Unity Launcher size?

Tags: unity, launcher, guest-session

I was wondering if it is possible to change the default size of the launcher during guest sessions? It is rather large, and a little bulky (opinion), and I was wondering if I could change it so every guest session would have a smaller (example 32px or whatever) launcher size?
(Ubuntu 12.04 and newer)

Thank you for your time and ansers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the [guest-session-prefs-lightdm kit](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession).

**README File:**

> guest-session-prefs-lightdm is a convenience kit that makes it easier
>   for a system admin to configure the guest session feature provided by
>   the lightdm package. The preferences are set via shell commands in
>   these two files:
>
> ```
> /etc/guest-session/prefs.sh
> /etc/guest-session/auto.sh
> ```
>
> The kit is shipped with the settings I made on my own computer. Some
>   may share my preferences, but most admins who install
>   guest-session-prefs-lightdm will probably make changes and/or
>   additions to those settings.
>
> My aim is to give the admins options, and the framework the kit offers
>   for configuring guest sessions may be of greater interest than the
>   particular settings that I happen to like. Still, my code snippets can
>   serve as models.
>
> See also http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1566078
>
> I would suggest that you install guest-session-prefs-lightdm as is,
>   and take it from there when you have reviewed the resulting changes in
>   behavior.

### Ubuntu 12.04

**1)** Go to [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) to download the [guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12.tar.gz](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12.tar.gz)  package to your ~/Downloads folder.

**2)** Open a Terminal window and type:

- `cd ~/Downloads/`
- `tar -xf guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12.tar.gz`
- `cd guest-session-prefs-lightdm-0.12/`
- `sudo ./install.sh`

**Note:** *The script install.sh will tell you if you need to install any package to complete the installation. eg (gettext)*

**3)** Edit the /etc/guest-session/auto.sh file to add the command to resize the Launcher icons.

- `sudo nano /etc/guest-session/auto.sh`

Add the following lines to the file:

```
# Change Launcher icon size to 32
gconftool-2 --type int --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/icon_size 32
```

[image]

Save the changes with <kbd>Ctrol</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

**4)**Finally you can lOgout and login in the guest account to see the changes.

Result:

[image]

### Ubuntu 12.10 & 13.04

Thes steps are the same as 12.04, the only change would be the command to resize the icons.

Use:

```
# Change Launcher icon size to 32
gsettings set org.compiz.unityshell:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/  icon-size 32
```

instead the gconftool-2 command.

**NOTE:** This kit by default has examples like display an info dialog, or create a link to a folder. You can change it according to your needs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for all the information! Very clear and easy to understand.